# WordPress search widget native constructing different query string on relative pages

Tags: wordpress

I am a beginner Wordpress developer and am developing a WordPress search plugin with some AI based API involved.

How does plugin work?

- User fire some search in search widget
- If the query text is identical to AI based API we get some textual result and relevant URL (within site) to redirect the page.
- If query text is strange or beyond AI's scope of identification then we invoke search widget submit. By calling 'el.submit()' JS method.

What is the problem?

- My plugin is working as expected on the home page. Ex `www.example.com`
  If I search 'Google search console' (Which is an internal article) then search widget invoking the native search and search widget submits the form. URL becomes www.example.com/?s=Google+search+console.
- Problem: When I go to www.example.com/blog and fire the same search query then URL becoming `www.example.com/blog/?s=Google%20search%20console`
- Resulting in 'Page not found'.

It is weird. Do somebody had any idea what is happening here or why two different constructs of a search query on relative pages within the site.

Comment: What is "AI based API"?

Comment: @DoNhuVy a REST API which accepts input and determines (AI logic is there) what user's intent behind the search query like whether he/she was looking for 'blog', 'about us' or anything else.